# WebView not working with INTERNET permission set

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-webview

I have a very simple application and I cannot make the WebView to show google.com (That's what I'm using to test

this is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bantol.mpp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MPPActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is the code I'm using in my `MPPActivity`:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
    }
```

The WebView shows **Web page not available** but no errors or messages on the LogCat

What am I missing?

I'm testing this on my device not the emulator.

Comment: Remove everything but the loadUrl() call and try it again. Guess you have a working connection on your device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`www.google.com` is not a url, but `http://www.google.com` is. Fix your loadUrl() call to hold a proper url and it should work (if you have a valid connection, etc.).

Comment: Hehehe... how easy was that.. Thanks!

Comment: @Davek804 you mean `http://google.com` instead of `http://www.google.com` or just `google.com`?

Comment: Ooops! the URL that I typed, but not the one that showed up is indeed http : // url . com